# Wordpress user’s activity feed in MixPanel is empty

Tags: wordpress, mixpanel

I just added the snippet to the header of my wordpress theme adding a statement to identify each user using its distinct_id:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
(function(e,a){if(!a.__SV){var b=window;try{var c,l,i,j=b.location,g=j.hash;c=function(a,b){return(l=a.match(RegExp(b+"=([^&]*)")))?l[1]:null};g&&c(g,"state")&&(i=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(c(g,"state"))),"mpeditor"===i.action&&(b.sessionStorage.setItem("_mpcehash",g),history.replaceState(i.desiredHash||"",e.title,j.pathname+j.search)))}catch(m){}var k,h;window.mixpanel=a;a._i=[];a.init=function(b,c,f){function e(b,a){var c=a.split(".");2==c.length&&(b=b[c[0]],a=c[1]);b[a]=function(){b.push([a].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,
0)))}}var d=a;"undefined"!==typeof f?d=a[f]=[]:f="mixpanel";d.people=d.people||[];d.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==f&&(a+="."+f);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};d.people.toString=function(){return d.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};k="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
for(h=0;h<k.length;h++)e(d,k[h]);a._i.push([b,c,f])};a.__SV=1.2;b=e.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.async=!0;b.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===e.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";c=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(b,c)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
mixpanel.init("mytoken", {
  loaded: function(mixpanel) {
      var distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
      mixpanel.identify(distinct_id);
      mixpanel.people.set_once('$first_name', distinct_id);
  }
});
</script>`
```

And it seems to work quite well. Right now if I go to "segmentation" and I choose to filter events by "people" > "first name" I can se a full report of who has send each event and if I go to "people" > "explore" I can see a full list of the users as expected but when I choose one of the users and I get into "people" > "user profile" the "activity feed" section is empty and also there is nothing in the "live view".
Our events have been created using the "set up tracking" option in the top-right menu and I understand that we have created some kind of relation between the events and each user distinct_id but it is not set in the right way and any advice to figure out the correct setting will be extremely apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from the answer that I get from the mixpanel comunity:
http://community.mixpanel.com/t/wordpress-users-activity-feed-is-empty/1232

> Events tracked via Autotrack are not shown within the activity feed of
>   users within the "Explore" report and are also not shown within the
>   "Live View" report. If you'd like event data to be shown within either
>   of these two locations your best bet would be to use a hard-coded
>   mixpanel.track() call. Events fired via the mixpanel.track() method
>   will be shown within the activity feed as well as "Live View".

Answer (score 1):

It is because the activity feed and the live view in mixpanel shows the list of events tracked within the site that you must manually code in your website like `mixpanel.track(eventName)` . Since you are only using `mixpanel.identify()` and `mixpanel.people.set_once()` which stores the profile in mixpanel, you are seeing it in explore and segmentation.
In mixpanel you must code everything that you need to track. 
From [mixpanel documentation](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript), example of simple event tracking :

```
mixpanel.track(
   "Played song",
   {"genre": "hip-hop"}
);
```

Comment: Thanks @prajwal ! Also the problem was that I was using the autotrack. CHeck my answer below.

Comment: Seems like autotrack was new feature added. When i was implementing mixpanel, i havenot seen it. I can see few changes in mixpanel dashboard as well.
Well i got to know new thing reading your q/a . Thanks and good luck.